# After entering a search term and clicking "search," the page brings users back up to the top and they have to scroll down to see the results

Tags: javascript, php, css, sql, search

*(Apologies if I am not using correct terminology--I am a student and this question falls outside of what we are learning about in terms of having a curated formal reading/resources list to refer to!)*

I am working on a final project (assignment=PHP site with a section that searches an SQL database and returns results in a table; have been learning Bootstrap to try to style the project site). I've got a lot finally working that I had been stuck on (thanks to others posting their questions/issues on this site, actually)!

**However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to best search for resources on a problem I am having with displaying search results on my project site**: Right now, when a user enters a search term and clicks the "search" button, they are taken back to the top of the web page and then have to scroll back down to see the search results.

**Below is what I've tried in terms of finding appropriate reading:**

- I have Googled terms related to displaying search results, and come up with a lot of usability guidance (which was useful and I bookmarked to read later), but no technical details (or none that I recognized).

  > "how to get search results to return to search bar in page"
  >
  > "how to get search results to return to specific place in page"
  >
  > "displaying search results"
  >
  > "displaying search results + load"
- I both scanned the "How To" side menu and searched the W3 site: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/default.asp

  > "search results"
- I searched similar terms as above here

**Based on the above results I've gone through, here are my questions for moving forward:**

- It seems like this is something I will have to use JavaScript for--is this correct?
- Are there other search terms that would be useful to try? (e.g., I'm going to start reading about "focus" now)

Thank you so much for any guidance in terms of narrowing down my search options!!!

---

**UPDATE!**

**What worked:**
Adding a [form action](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_formaction.asp) attribute to the "search" and "clear" buttons, and setting those attributes to load to the anchor for the search section of the page!!!

**How I found it:**
I had been searching for how to call multiple actions on a button in javascript (so I could have both the focus action and the clear action, e.g., on one of the buttons), and one result was [this page about "multiple form submit for different form action"](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/html/multiple+form+submit+for+different+form+action), which led me to search for more about formaction, which led me to https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html-button-formaction-attribute/, and ultimately the [w3schools page](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_formaction.asp).

Thanks again for setting me down the right path, Ken!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this gives you an idea that will help you figure out what you are trying to achieve.

```
function getFocus() {
  document.getElementById("mySearch").focus();
}

function loseFocus() {
  document.getElementById("btn").focus();
}
```

```
.mySearch{margin-top: 100%;}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button type="button" id="btn" onclick="getFocus()">Get focus</button>

<p id="p">Try to click this</p>

<button type="button" onclick="loseFocus()">Lose focus</button>

<input type="search" class="mySearch" id="mySearch" placeholder="Search field..">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is super-helpful! I just pasted this into a new file and it worked there and now I'll play around with it more. It looks like focus is the way to go with this in terms of additional reading--I'm going to start with W3schools stuff (any other suggested readings are welcome)!